# How to change android screen during function

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to change the screen of an app during a function is running.

```
public void StartRecording(View view)
{
    start_button.setEnabled(false);
    stop_button.setEnabled(true);
    recording = true;

    while(recording==true)
    {
       // Here is a code that changes many views on the screen

       try {
           Thread.sleep(1000);
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}
```

function StartRecording() is called by clicking the start_button in the xml file.

recording is set to false when clicking the stop_button.

The views on the screen should change, wait a second, change again, wait a second and so on.
But what happens is that the function waits until the loop is finished and then shows only the final screen change. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks ahead : )

Edit:

I tried using Handler and it has the same result..

```
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
{
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        tv.setText((String) msg.obj);
    }
};
```

tv is a textView. Instead of using tv.setText just above the try{} in the code above, I sent a message to mHandler to change the text, and it still changes it only after the whole startRecording function is over.

Now, what am I doing wrong? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong

you are calling `sleep` wait the UI Thread, that is responsible for drawing your views and handle events. If you want to schedule 10 different redrawing of your views, you can use and [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and its [postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)) method

Comment: And what if I want to change the views every second until a button is pressed and stops the function? 10 was just an example

Comment: please have a look at what I added to the question.. I've been working on this the whole day and can't seem to get it right

Comment: Nevermind, sorry for the mess i FINALLY got it.. : ) Thank you!